# "name 'win32api' is not defined" - error yet package is present?

Tags: python, winapi, python-3.x

I installed win32api on my Win7 (64-bit PC) using `pip install pywin32`

I am then able to import the package using:

```
from win32api import keybd_event, SetCursorPos, mouse_event
```

but when accessing it as part of my code:

```
def press(*args):
    '''
    one press, one release.
    accepts as many arguments as you want. e.g. press('left_arrow', 'a','b').
    '''
    for i in args:
        win32api.keybd_event(VK_CODE[i], 0,0,0)
        time.sleep(.05)
        win32api.keybd_event(VK_CODE[i],0 ,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP ,0)
```

I receive the error shown below. Does anyone have any insight in what might be wrong or how best for me to determine the root cause.

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bartis\Desktop\Python\Point\sendKeys.py", line 164, in <module>
    press('backspace')
  File "C:\Users\bartis\Desktop\Python\Point\sendKeys.py", line 121, in press
    win32api.keybd_event(VK_CODE[i], 0,0,0)
NameError: name 'win32api' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

The `from` statement you used only imports the names listed after the `import` keyword. It doesn't import the name `win32api` itself. Either add an `import win32api` statement or change  `win32api.keybd_event` to just `keybd_event`.

Comment: Ross - I made the suggested change, import win32api, saved the file and re-ran. I amd receiving the same error message?

Comment: Sorry hit send to quickly. meant to add the error message - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bartis\Desktop\Python\Point\sendKeys.py", line 164, in <module>
    press('backspace')
  File "C:\Users\bartis\Desktop\Python\Point\sendKeys.py", line 121, in press
    win32api.keybd_event(VK_CODE[i], 0,0,0)

Comment: My mistake. The error message did change. Thank you for your time and the help